# ASP.NET MVC version of WP-Cron

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cron

Wordpress has an interesting plugin called `wp-cron`. It acts like a cron, but doesn't require "real" cron to be set up.

The way it works is pretty simple: once you specify the cron frequency (eg. once a day at 3am), whenever someone visits your site, it checks if it's time to execute the cron task (last visit was pre-cron, current visit is post-cron), and does it.

Is there something (on NuGet?) that does this for ASP.NET MVC (4)? I can't imagine that it's terribly complex to write, so I assume someone solved this problem already. A quick Google just turned up "write a Windows service" or "set up *real* cron."

Workflow Foundation might work as well, although I imagine it would be more work than something you can implement wp-cron style.

Comment: You mean something like [`Quartz.net`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), or simpler? You can also use a little finesse and play with the [cache timeouts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want something to schedule tasks, you can look at [`Quarts.net`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). it's a complete library based around that sort of thing. if you want something down and dirty, [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) has a good method (that was used here on StackOverflow) which takes advantage of caching and expiration.